# How To create Transparent buttons on libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a transparent button how to do that in libgdx 
i tried https://github.com/cobolfoo/gdx-skineditor this skin editor but couldnt do it either

Comment: Are you using the scene2d api? How _exactly_ should the button look like? Fully transparent (invisible) or just partially transparent? **Show some code** - what did you try so far?

Comment: as i sad i tried with the skin editor yes i am using  scene2d api 75 80 percent transperant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need buttons with concrete percentage of transparency and then you will not change that percentage anymore it's much easier to create the buttons images with desired transparency level in some graphics editor (e.g. Photoshop) and then use them in your project.

Comment: thanks for the replay , after some research ı did it with textureatlas